# Cygwin & Python: pip install <package> cause error "Files/directories not found in"

Tags: python, installation, pip, cygwin

Running under Cygwin, I attempt the following:

```
$ pip install --no-cache-dir ibm_db
Collecting ibm_db
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3f/61/389c6decacfed61c2724005b8c2be61f2c699f731b53af13517e5a0e6e98/ibm_db-2.0.9.tar.gz (782kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 788kB 2.6MB/s
Files/directories not found in /tmp/pip-install-aaq0fljf/ibm-db/pip-egg-info
$
```

Always under Cygwin, I successfully install other packages with pip.  This same package installs successfully under Linux.  Thus why is this particular package incompatible with Cygwin?  What can be the cause of the error?

Version of Python:  Python 3.6.4 (default, Jan  7 2018, 15:53:53)

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: Source dists with C/C++ extensions are rarely installed successfully with Cygwin; better is to clone the source code, build a wheel that contains all the compiled extensions, and install that one.